# Multiple Values Parameter with Blank value in SQL Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report which I need to be able to show all values for 1 required parameter or be able to type in a group of values in the optional parameter.

First parameter (required): Manufacturer.

Second parameter (optional): leave blank for all parts from that manufacturer or the ability to type in 5+ different part numbers and have just those show.

I can't use a list of available values since there are 100,000 or more parts in my database. I can't use Null with multiple values without a workaround using available values. I saw that one in my research. The end user doesn't want a subquery pulling up a list of part #'s for them to sort through to pick what they want.

When I leave @Part blank or put 1 part number in it works as expected.

I get an error when I have it run with more than 1 part.  The error reads: "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Here is the code I think is relevant.

```
(SELECT branch, mfg, part
FROM partact
WHERE mfg IN (@Mfg) AND 
(part IN (@Part) OR @Part IN (''))) a
```

It is part of a larger query, but the larger query seems to be working fine based on it working while blank and with 1 part.

What I've tested so far:
Swapped @Part IN ('') for @Part = ''

Swapped parentheses around in a few ways. It processes well as it is set now.

Comment: I've tested this as well.

    =Join(Parameters!TestCase.Value, ",")
Using that as the Parameter Expression. Tried a Split as well.

Answer (score 0):

To handle a comma separated field, you'll need to use a function to split the string into separate rows.

With the STRING_SPLIT function, your statement changes to:

```
(part IN (SELECT  TRIM(value) FROM  STRING_SPLIT(@Part, ',')) OR @Part = '')
```

If your SQL Server is 2016/Compatability 130 or higher, you can use the built in STRING_SPLIT function.  Otherwise you'll need to use a custom splitter function, but the general statement would be the same.

**UPDATE**
You can find a write up of the [custom splitter by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  Its a lengthy article but it is good to understand the issues that can be caused by a splitter.

Comment: Thank you for the response Wes. 
We are not on a high enough compatibility level for String_Split. I'm not familiar with a custom splitter function. What is that?

Comment: I looked into what a splitter function is. They sound neat, but I've never written a function before and I wasn't sure about this part. Does my Report Builder have access to custom functions if I make one for this?

Comment: You'll need to have permission to create a function in your database.  The Report Builder connection account will need Execute permission on the functions as well. The link I posted should provide everything you'll need to create it.